# Combining async.each and async.series

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, async.js

I want to combine async.each and async.series but I'm getting unexpected results.

```
async.each([1, 2], function(item, nloop) {
    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            console.log("1");
            callback();
        },
        function(callback) {
            console.log("2");
            callback();
        },
        function(callback) {
            console.log("3");
            callback();
        },
        function(callback) {
            nloop();
        }
    ]);
},function(){

});
```

I would expect this code to output `123123`.
Instead I'm getting `112233`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async.each()` [applies the function iterator to each item in array in parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback).
If you want to do it serially, you should use `eachSeries()`.

Additionally, You should use the final callback in `async.series(taskArray, callback)`:

```
async.eachSeries([1, 2], function(item, nextItem) {
    async.series([
        function(next) {
            console.log("1");
            next();
        },
        function(next) {
            console.log("2");
            next();
        },
        function(callback) {
            console.log("3");
            next();
        }
    ], nextItem);
},function(){

});
```